# Why shape parameter is required in scipy.lognorm?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-science

I try to generate probability density function for log-normal distribution. All theory goes that we only need location and scale parameters to describe the distribution (*mu* - mean of logarithmic values and *sigma* - standard deviation of logarithmic values). I use `scipy` library to generate PDF, namely `lognorm.pdf`. The issue is that this function requires `shape` parameter. I don't need this parameter (I guess) but I'm forced to use it. I don't know what exactly this parameter describes.

Log-normal `scale` parameter is in fact standard deviation of logarithmic values. When I generate log-normal PDF with required `shape` parameter it turns out that `shape` behaves like standard deviation. At least it looks like this. I know that some other distributions have to be provided with `shape` parameter which defines overall shape of a distribution but in case of lognormal I have no clue why we need it if it's not required by theory.

I'm confused with what's going on with this `shape` in this library. Another question is: if I really have to use this parameter then what value should I use? Or how to calculate it?

This is my code where I fixed `scale` parameter to show how `shape` changes the plots:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_x = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.001)
pdf_log1 = lognorm.pdf(data_x, s=0.2, loc=0, scale=1)
pdf_log2 = lognorm.pdf(data_x, s=1, loc=0, scale=1)
pdf_log3 = lognorm.pdf(data_x, s=2, loc=0, scale=1)

plt.plot(data_x, pdf_log1, color='red', label='shape=0.2')
plt.plot(data_x, pdf_log2, color='blue', label='shape=1')
plt.plot(data_x, pdf_log3, color='black', label='shape=2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: With `s` equal to 1, .5, and .25, your code produces the same plot as the illustrative one in the Wiki article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Log-normal-pdfs.png (and `data_x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.001)`)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: The last sentence in the *Notes* section of the [`lognorm` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm) explains how to convert `mu` and `sigma` (the parameters of the underlying normal distribution) to the shape and scale parameters of `lognorm`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, and it goes that standard deviation (of underlying normal dist) is equal to s (shape). So, to my understanding, shape of lognormal = standard deviation of underlying normal, right? However, I read everywhere that scale of lognormal is in fact standard distribution of underlying normal. And this is where I get confused about scale and  shape. They both seem to refer to std of normal distr.

Comment: @hpaulj but plot in the Wiki is built on mean and std of variable's natural logarithm (which is further location and scale of log-normal). According to that, shape = sigma ( standard deviation). However std = scale. So scale =shape? I don't get the relation between them

Comment: For a *normal distribution*, the standard deviation and the scale of the distribution are the same thing. The SciPy implementation of the log-normal distribution is not parametrized by the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution, so the scale parameter of SciPy's log-normal distribution is not the same as the standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution.  *All* of SciPy's univariate continuous distributions have a location and scale parameter, and sometimes the location-scale convention doesn't match the more common parametrization of the distribution.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation. I followed this article: https://statisticsbyjim.com/probability/lognormal-distribution/ where scale, loc are described as std and mean of normal distribution. Just to close this topic up, I'll give a practical example. Let's say X is log-normally distributed and its values are X=[20,22,25,30,60]. Now, how can I calculate scale, location and shape of lognormal?